# Compute joint probability of two variables without using copulas

Tags: joint-distribution, computational-statistics, gumbel-distribution

I have two timeseries one for a three-day accumulated rainfall and another one for a daily storm surge height. I would like to calculate the probability of a certain rainfall depth with a certain storm surge height. For instance, the probability of 8 inches of rain falling on the same day where there is a storm surge height of 0.5 meters. I understand there is an advanced way of computing that with copulas but is there a simpler way of computing that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the copula approach? The popularity of copulae is generally *because of their simplicity*. Knowing the marginals and fitting a copula is sufficient to describe the multivariate distribution

Comment: @statsplease I haven't worked with copulas before and my impression was that they are a bit complex. I have several scenarios that I need to calculate the joint probabilities of with the goal of choosing the most probable scenarios to be selected for a hydraulic model run. To that end, I figured using simple joint probability methods might provide the desired output. But out of curiosity, do you recommend any copula type?

Comment: You would let the data infer which copula family to go with. There's nothing particularly complicated about copulae. If you can grasp a bivariate distribution then there isn't much of a jump to copulas from there. If you're looking for more specific help you might want to flesh out some further detail in your question. What does the empirical multivariate relationship look like?

Comment: @statsplease Isn't that already shown by the marginal probability distribution curves shown in red? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry made an error in the previous comment. Can you reproduce that plot where each of the (x,y) points is replaced with $(F_{X},F_{Y})$ where $F_{i}$ is the cumulative distribution function of each marginal? Keep both plots. I wanted to see the relationship between the uniforms, which is what a copula would be fit to.

Comment: @statsplease I have now added the CDF of the two variables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140646/discussion-between-michael-getachew-and-statsplease).